# Change many2many field tags color odoo

Tags: python, xml, field, odoo, background-color

How i can chage color, for tag in my many2many field.

example:
[image]

Comment: Please specify the Odoo version. On the newest Odoo versions, you can change the color simply by clicking on the tag.

Comment: @Kenly 13.0 my odoo version

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `color_field` option to specify the field to be used as the color index, Odoo will check if there is a color field on the related model.

If you want to define a many2many field in your custom model (`'custom.model'`) for which you defined the target model to `'custom.model.tags'` and want to use the many2many_tags widget with `color_field` option, you will need to define an integer field in the target model (`'custom.model.tags'`).

***Example:***

```py
class CustomModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.model'

    tag_ids = fields.Many2many('custom.model.tags')


class CustomModelTags(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.model.tags'

    color = fields.Integer()
```

Define the many2many field like following:

```xml
<field name="tag_ids" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'color_field': 'color'}"/>
```

***Edit:***

To set the color of the tag, Odoo will prepare the [render context](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/relational_fields.js#L2273) (get the color field name and record value) and call the [qweb render](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/relational_fields.js#L2344) method using that render context and in the [FieldMany2ManyTag](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml#L768) template, it will simply add a class [o_tag_color_#{color}](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml#L772) to the `tag` where `color` is the value of the color field.

Odoo gets the value of the color field from the record data for each tag, so there is no option to pass the value in options or context.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically change color based on a value ? Can we pass value to that integer field ?

Comment: @NinjaBat Check my edit

Comment: Odoo gets the value of the color field from the record data for each tag. This made me to try compute field to pass value for each record. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using many2many_tags. In this case you could use 'color_field'

```
 <field name="field_ids" 
        widget="many2many_tags" 
        options="{'color_field': 'color'}"/>
```